# React Native, change button color and render different text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I created 3 buttons in row, I want that when user click a button, that button color will change It will display different text like in the image bellow. Can anyone tell me how can do this? please

[image]

I created a AppTabButton component for that code is below

```
function AppTabButton({
  title1,
  title2,
  title3,
  onPress,
  style,
  color1 = colors.black,
  color2 = colors.black,
  color3 = colors.black,
  bttnclr1,
  bttnclr2,
  bttnclr3,
}) {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.bttnCmn, style]}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button1, bttnclr1]}>
        <Text style={[styles.btnTxt, {color: color1}]}>{title1}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button2, bttnclr2]}>
        <Text style={[styles.btnTxt, {color: color2}]}>{title2}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button3, bttnclr3]}>
        <Text style={[styles.btnTxt, {color: color3}]}>{title3}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

and the screen where I'm using it

```
class Wallet extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <Image source={imagePath.logo} style={styles.logo} />
          <Image source={imagePath.bell} style={styles.bell} />
          <Image source={imagePath.profilePic} style={styles.profilepic} />
        </View>
        <Text style={[style.fontSize30Semi, styles.font30]}>My Wallet</Text>
        <AppTabButton
          title1="Cash"
          title2="Coupons"
          title3="Points"
          style={styles.tabButton}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you mean when you click a tab-button to be active and change in style ?

Comment: yup, and also change the text or something i want to render